# Iptables in linux

Tags: ubuntu, centos, rhel, iptables

Please explain me the use of bold character below

iptables **-A** INPUT **-i** eth0 **-p** tcp --dport 443 **-m** **state** **--state** NEW,ESTABLISHED **-j** ACCEPT

**-A**
**-i** 
**-p**
**-m**
**state**
**--state**
**-j**

Comment: Do you try reading iptables's manpage?

Answer (score 4):

[`man iptables`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables) will tell you most of this and has an extensive list of examples.

`-t` Specify the table to add the rule to (by default, the `filter` table)

`-A` Append the rule to the specified chain of rules (as opposed to `-I` for insert at the beginning).

`-i` Set the interface for this rule to match on (default of `*` or all)

`-p` match on the protocol of the packet

`-m` Use an extended packet matching module as specified, in you case packet states.

`--state` For the `state` extended module, match any `NEW` or `ESTABLISHED` packets (via `ip_conntrack` - ip connection tracking info stored in  memory)

`-j` "Jump" the packet to the specified target, the builtin ACCEPT is to allow the packet through

For some of these concepts it helps to know how packets traverse `iptables` as well:

[image: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Communication_Networks/IP_Tables]

Each of the square boxes is a `table` (`-t`)
The columns are `chains` (what you append/insert/delete rules in)

Image from http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Communication_Networks/IP_Tables

Answer (score 1):

i -specifies the interfaces on which a packet was received

p - indicates the protocol as tcp, udp or icmp

The -A a parameter does not mean ACCEPT but append the rule to the end of the iptables INPUT chain

-m state - specifies  a  match  to  use here it loads the state module and allow only NEW and ESTABLISHED connections

-j - specifies the jump target (what to do if the packet matches it) here to ACCEPT the connection

other targets are DROP, DENY, LOG

Answer (score 0):

-A = ACCEPT

-i = Interface

-p= Protocol

I have read this while I am trying to learn

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/01/iptables-fundamentals/